# passing sqlite parameters into a python code from another python code

Tags: python, sqlite, arguments

I checked similar topics but could not find what I am looking for.
I simply want to call a py script which includes a sqlite code from another py code and also pass macro variables to it. I simply want to assign a macro variable as run_date and pass the values I gave here to another python code I am calling, however I receive this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "0_Data_Cleaning_Pipeline.py", line 42, in <module>
    weekly_transactions['report_end_date'] = run_date
NameError: name 'run_date' is not defined

# CONNECT DATABASE
import pandas as pd
import os
import subprocess
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlite3
# connection to database
db = sqlite3.connect('gencodb.db')
# cursor
cursor = db.cursor()
# Libraries

# ENTER THE DATA WEEKS
run_date = '22/02/2020'

subprocess.call(" python 0_Data_Cleaning_Pipeline.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: what do you mean by a macro variable? and how are you calling the another python code? via the terminal or inside this code as a module?

Comment: I want to pass an argument to another code such as run_date. I have this code such as  weekly_transactions['report_end_date'] = run_date in the second code and I want to control it from a master code like I copied above.  I am running it in atom editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass run date as a argument to the program you are calling with `subprocess.call` like so

```py
subprocess.call("python 0_Data_Cleaning_Pipeline.py".split() + [run_date], shell=True)
```

and in `0_Data_Cleaning_Pipeline.py` you can access the passed argument with

```py
import sys

run_date = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: I should copy this into the  0_Data_Cleaning_Pipeline  code right? I tried it but did not work.                                                                                                                           import sys

run_date = sys.argv[1]

Comment: yes, copy that into the other file. When you say something does not work, please also provide the errors that you get.

Comment: I changed run_date = sys.argv[1] to run_date = sys.argv[0] and it works now! However I have a few other arguments I want to pass, how can I add them by using the same syntax you showed above?

Comment: you add them with the list with `run_date` like `[run_date, varA, varB]` and so on, but make sure they are string or atleast castable to `str`. then you can access them `sys.argv[1]`, `sys.argv[2]` and so on

Comment: its is weird that you are getting the parameter at `sys.argv[0]`. may I ask what OS are you using and the python version?

Comment: Python version is 3.7.4 and I am using Windows. I applied your suggestion into my code such as run_date = '22/02/2020'
this_wk = '22FEB20'
last_wk = '15FEB20'
prev_wk = '08FEB20'

# weekly_vars = [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk]

subprocess.call("python 0_Data_Cleaning_Pipeline.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell = True)   I received this error : NameError: name 'this_wk' is not defined

Comment: I added them into the 2nd code such as run_date = sys.argv[0]
this_wk = sys.argv[1]
last_wk = sys.argv[2]
prev_wk = sys.argv[3]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208772/discussion-between-syfluqs-and-cagdas-kanar).